# Два балла. Прав ли учитель?

Tags: синтаксис

Оценка "два" дана за выполнение синтаксического задания в 8 классе. (Как составлять схему, учитель не объяснял.)

[image: Грамматическое задание]

Answer (score 3):

Что-то не верится, что в 8 классе не объяснили, как составлять схему. Два ставится за 50% выполненной работы. Я вот вижу, что Вы в тексте вообще не выделили деепричастный оборот и его не подчеркнули как член предложения - обстоятельство, "сливаясь" у Вас глагол, а не деепричастие, "на солнце" - творительный падеж вместо предложного, предлоги вообще не подчёркнуты, а они подчёркиваются вместе с существительным, характеристика предложения неполная, значит,неправильная, нужно:(Повеств.,невоскл.,простое, двусоставное, полное, распр., осложнено однородными членами с обобщающим словом и обособленным обстоятельством, выраженным деепр. об.)

[ О:О, О - =,/*.*._/__]. Знаки препинания при однор. чл. с обобщ. словом неверны: после обобщающего слова двоеточие, после однородных членов тире.

Я считаю, что учитель прав.

Comment: Людмила, у вас на  схеме идет сперва подлежащее и сказуемое, а в примере наоборот. Если сперва поставить сказуемое, а потом подлежащее, это ошибка?

Comment: И ещё: в квадратных скобках - ДО? А что означают точки? И две линии после скабок?

Comment: Расшифровываю схему: [ О:О, О -  обобщающее слово, двоеточие, два однородных члена, тире перед сказуемым =, дальше выделяем дееприч. оборот: запятая, вертикальные черты, в них дееприч. об.,/.._/,после них запятая, подлежащее__]. После закрывающей квадратной скобки точка - указатель на повествовательную интонацию. Да, там в вертикальных чертах непонятное, это я пыталась изобразить внизу точку- тире, а искать символы времени не было. А насчёт порядка подлежащего и сказуемого, порядок должен соответствовать реальному положению в предложение, иначе будет ошибка.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!